# Extend keycloak storage provider

Tags: java, keycloak

I've got a problem with implementing own LDAP storage provider which I will do it only for  extend `searchForUserByUserAttribute` functionality, because there is some hard-coded escape strategy.

Here are my first attempts to approach the topic:

1. I've tried to copy all code from `keycloak-ldap-federation` and replacing provider id, but in that case form responding for creating ldap configuration cannot resolve a valid view. There was a many blank labels and inputs.
2. I've also extended `LDAPStorageProviderFactory` and `LDAPStorageProvider` with my own provider and factory but after deploying it on keycloak, doesn't consider it. There is only base `LDAPStorageProvider`.

How to achieve my goal?

edit:
There is no console logs about errors. But when I added my custom ldap provider which was as same as original LdapStorageProvider except changed ProviderId to custom-ldap.

[Adding ldap screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhtxT.png)

I found some difference on network dev tools. In original ldap provider html which was getting from server is called user-storage-ldap.html, but in my custom provider it was user-storage-generic.html.

Comment: Can you please post some code snippet or any exception trace that you are getting?

Comment: I've added some information in post about trying implement another ldap provider. Please take a look!

Comment: Did you got the fix?

Comment: I have posted similar 
https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/migrating-keycloak-15-to-keycloak20-instead-of-user-storage-ldap-html-it-is-calling-user-storage-generic-html-at-user-federation-add-storage-provider/19302